# How can I delete an "accepted answer"?

Tags: support

I tried to delete the linked "[***answer***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284124/usage-of-the-word-hand-in-the-context/284128?noredirect=1#comment632845_284128)" but failed ***as it was accepted***.

There are some comments I can't take any more and I would like to delete it.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Fight the urge to reply to comments that seem too much to you.  Let the Answer stand and move on.

Comment: @medica I don't think it is any harassment and I understand well his point. Would you insist on putting "open" before "compound noun"? What difference does it make when the question is completely irrelvant to how to classify compound nouns?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to answer your questions. Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about deleting your answer.

Comment: @medica That's the answer I wanted. "There is nothing I can do about it." Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There is a use but unluckily also an abuse of comments on this site, http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5394/what-about-downvoting-comments, but you should not get discouraged by that. There are users who rarely ask questions or make answers, but tend to be very active on comments instead (I wonder why). The fact is that the "core business" of this site is Q&A, not comments, and you are showing the right attitude. –

Comment: @Josh61 People are different and the way they use or rather enjoy this site should be respected, I think. But they have to stop when the other side is not arguing their opinion/comment is completely wrong and seems to be agreeing with them to some degree. I agree with you that it is a Q&A site and they have to post their own answer so that poorer ones can be downvoted or deleted. I never mind getting downvoted or deleting my answer if I find mine is poorer than others'.

Answer (score 3):

If the answer has a score of -1 or less, three [users with 20k+ rep](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can delete it even if it's accepted and moderators can always delete an answer if they so choose. I won't guarantee that I'll always delete an answer if a flag asks me to (especially since I've even *undeleted* useful self-deleted posts), but if an answer is unsalvageably bad or wrong, I probably wouldn't see a good reason to keep it around against the author's wishes.

On the other hand, if the answer is fine but there are comments that cross a line (beyond normal criticism of the answer) or are otherwise excessive, it would be more appropriate to flag those instead. When things get heated, it's often best for a moderator to just put a comment lock on for a week to let things cool down.

Note: In this case, the moderator chose to leave the answer and delete the comments. (There was no option to apply a comment lock in 2015—that was only added many years later.)